# UAC popup launch taking time after clicking on Install button

Tags: wix

I am developing a WIX Installer for an application. When I click on the Install button, next UI is coming which is a progress bar UI. 
The issues is the time it takes to start the status messages to the users before UAC popup clicked yes.

Is there any way to show wait message before this delayed UAC popup to the user?

Thanks,
Sandeep

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported by Windows Installer. These actions are executed immediately one after another, but it takes some time until Windows Installer processes the elevation request.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if inserting a custom action into the UI sequence before ExecuteAction would allow you to specify [ActionText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367516%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [MsiProcessMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370354%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it into the progress dialog. Have you tried that?